# Why is my AlexNet to train on CIFAR10 is not working?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to implement AlexNet and train on CIFAR10. However, the loss is not diminishing. Can you please tell me any problem?

```
class Alexnet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3,64,3,2,1),nn.ReLU(),nn.MaxPool2d(2)) 
    self.conv2=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(64,192,3,1,padding=2),nn.MaxPool2d(2)) 
    self.conv3=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(192,384,3,1,padding=1),nn.ReLU()) 
    self.conv4=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(384,256,3,1,padding=1),nn.ReLU()) 
    self.conv5=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(256,256,3,1,padding=1),nn.ReLU(),nn.MaxPool2d(2)) 
    self.dropout=nn.Dropout(0.3)
    self.fc1=nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(),nn.Linear(256*2*2,4096),nn.ReLU())
    self.fc2=nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4096,4096),nn.ReLU())
    self.fc3=nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4096,10),nn.ReLU())
  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.conv1(x)
    x=self.conv2(x)
    x=self.conv3(x)
    x=self.conv4(x)
    x=self.conv5(x)
    x=self.dropout(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)
    x=self.dropout(x)
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you train this model?

Comment: You need to provide more details, but you can start by removing that last ReLU in `.fc3`. BTW, I'd always prefer to use more official implementations, e.g., [this one](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/alexnet.py)

Comment: Thank you so much, as you sid, the ReLU in las fc3 was the problem